# @Autowired object not instantiated in a package, but does not work in different package

Tags: spring, components, autowired

I have **Package A** which contains a class that i have annotated as @Component.
**Package B** where I have @Atuowired it and its working fine.
But in **package C** @Autowired annotation doesnt seem to work.
What am I missing ?
I have tried naming the Component and also setting @Primary annotation

Comment: Show us some example code.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that may cause such behavior is component scanning. Check your component scanning for presence of packageC.

Component scanning annotation looks like this:

1. In case of annotation-based configuration:

   @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.your.base.package.name")
2. In case of xml configuration:

   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.your.base.package.name"/>`

You should check that your packageC is an internal package of your "com.your.base.package.name".

Read for further details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning